# Получить Array ID при определенном значении внутри

Tags: php, массивы

Имеется такой массив, нужно найти "10" где [][0]=159

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 405
            [1] => 22
            [2] => 22
        )
    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => 159
            [1] => 33
            [2] => 1
        )
    [25] => Array
        (
            [0] => 903
            [1] => 445
            [2] => 44
        )

    [33] => Array
        (
            [0] => 903
            [1] => 22
            [2] => 44
        )
 )
```

$col Выдает мне значение "1"

```
$did="159";
   $col=array_search($did,array_column($_SESSION['list'],0));
```

Уже все мануалы пересмотрел, в упор не вижу решения..

Comment: Спасибо, добрые люди! Да, я совсем новичок и не кодер вовсе :)...

Answer (score -1):

Если заранее известно что массив двухуровневый, то просто обойдите циклом:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($_SESSION['list'] as $key => $item) {
    if ($item[0] == $did) {
        $result[] = $key;
    }
}
```

Comment: Это то же самое что и у автора

Comment: Не правильно понял какой изначально массив у пользователя. Поправил.

Comment: @Qraxin, ваши минусы незаслуженные, ответ корректен. Не переживайте, такое бывает.

Comment: минусы заслуженные, поскольку первый вариант вообще не имел смысла, а второй вторичен, не отвечает на вопрос и алгоритмически тоже так себе. А вот переживать действительно не надо, не тот случай.

Answer (score -1):

```
    <?php
  $did='159';
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    # code...

$key = array_search($did,$value);
}

foreach ($data as $key2 => $row) {
    if ($row[$key] == $did) {
        break;
    }
}
echo $key2;

    ?>
```

Comment: Маловато циклов. Надо еще штук 5 добавить

Comment: с ключом [0] ,  ты это неверно)

Answer (score -1):

Мануалы здесь не нужны. Нужны самые элементарные познания в программировании.
Поиск значения в массиве - это **всегда** цикл.
Поэтому просто перебираем массив, пока не найдем нужное значение. Тупо подставляя условие, которое нам нужно.

```
foreach ($_SESSION['list'] as $key => $row) {
    if ($row[0] == $did) {
        break;
    }
}
echo $key;
```

Answer (score -1):

Можно воспользоваться `array_filter`:

```
$hay = [
    '15' => [150, 1, 5],
    '27' => [270, 2, 7],
    '39' => [390, 3, 9],
];

$id = 390;
// Через array_filter можно получить все записи, удовлетворяющие условию:
$filtered = array_filter($hay, function($el)use($id){return $el[0]===$id;});
$first = [key($filtered), reset($filtered)];
var_dump($first);
```

Ваш код тоже почти работает, он возвращает индекс найденного элемента, потому что ищет в результате array_column. Можно восстановить ключ:

```
$i = array_search($id, array_column($hay, 0));
var_dump(array_keys($hay)[$i]);
```

[3v4l](https://3v4l.org/rEXLl)

*Если есть возможность, можно сохранить ключи исходного массива в этом массиве и воспользоваться третьим параметром функции `array_column`*